# Discord command with spaces?

Tags: python, command, discord, bots, discord.py

I want to make a discord command with spaces in but it doesn't work, how can I fix that? I want the command to be *?help moderator* but I can't have spaces between the 2 words for some reason.

```
@commands.has_role('Staff')
@client.command(name='help moderator')

async def help_moderator(context):
    my_embed = discord.Embed(title="Moderator Plugin", color=0xFFC71C)
    my_embed.add_field(name="``?ban [member] (optional reason)``", value="Bans a member from the server",
                       inline=False)
    my_embed.add_field(name="``?tempban [member] [duration] (optional reason)``",
                       value="Temporarily bans a member from the server", inline=False)
    my_embed.add_field(name="``?mute [member] (optional reason)``", value="Mutes a member in the whole server",
                       inline=True)
    my_embed.add_field(name="``?tempmute [member] [duration] (optional reason)``",
                       value="Temporarily mutes a member in the server", inline=False)
    my_embed.add_field(name="``?kick [member] (optional reason)``", value="Kicks a member from the server",
                       inline=False)
    my_embed.add_field(name="``?unban [member]``", value="Unbans a member", inline=False)
    my_embed.add_field(name="``?unmute [member]``", value="Unmutes a member", inline=False)
    my_embed.set_thumbnail(
        url='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/765665083082407976/767502481922981928/ModHammer.png')

    my_embed.set_footer(text="Work in progress, these commands are not in function yet.")

    await context.message.channel.send(embed=my_embed)
```

Comment: Just use `startsWith` and `.split()` to get your command work and arguments

Comment: First of all, sorry for how weird my text look and where do I put ``startWith`` and ``split()``?

Comment: @Evorage where?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have command names or aliases with spaces inside using the [`Commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html) extension (it would cause some message parsing problems).

You'd have to use a [`on_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message) event in order to do this:

```py
from discord.utils import get

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    admin = get(message.guild.roles, name='Staff')
    if message.content.startswith('!help moderator') and admin in message.author.roles:
        #Your code here
```